# Magento 2 - How to save data in to a customer data custom section

Tags: magento2, section

I have a form that the visitor fills in and based on that form submission (to a controller) I need to save some data in a custom section.
I have my custom section working correctly but only returning a simple hard coded string currently:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\CustomerData;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
{
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        // this saves to the section but how to make this dynamic based on the form submission values?
        return [
            'customdata' => "Custom data",
        ];
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I save data to my custom section from a controller? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more info like is the data submitted on user wise or its just a normal form like contact us and you need to save that data in database and showed that data in Magento Admin ?

Comment: It's a "filtering" form (to filter products on the category page). I have it working now though (using sessions). I will post my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working by saving the posted form data in a session then returning that session data in the getSectionData() method:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\CustomerData;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
{

    public function __construct(\MyCompany\MyModule\Helper\Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }


    public function getSectionData()
    {
        return [
            'customdata' => $this->session->getMySession(),
        ];
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem right but it works and I am potentially only working with temporary data (I only save it to a model if customer is logged in)

p.s. The main reason I am using private data instead of directly displaying cookies/session data is to avoid Magento caching personalized data.